# Undo git push --tags

Tags: git

My repo uses lightweight tags but it's based on another repo that uses annotated tags. I wanted to change the reference for one our remote tags to point to my latest commit and to my bad luck I did;

git push --tags

Now all the annotated tags that we didn't want are pushed. How can I remove them forever from the git server?

Comment: You should have a look at `repo_root/.git/refs/tags/` on your server, sort files by creation time and delete the unwanted ones (the most recent should be the annotated tags, because they did not exist on the server before).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following git command:

```
git push origin :tag_name
```